# Change text when image is clicked

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know why paragraphs are not changing when image is clicked?
[image]

Comment: Any errors in your browser console?

Comment: No, I think it works fine

Comment: please don't ever post your code with an image.. try jsfiddle or jsbin

Comment: You should have the script just before the `</body>`.

Comment: Please include the code in the answer, not just an image. This way people could debug the code without having to copy it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you're getting some errors in your browser console, something about a syntax error.

It's likely because your text strings that you're inserting have a `"` in them. Try escaping those characters with `\"` instead, on line 17 and 18.

Your browser things your ending the string, because it sees a quote, but in reality, that's part of your string. Using `\"` means "don't use this as a closing quote, actually print out a quote character".

Alternatively, you could change your strings to start and end with single quote `'`, but you'd then have to escape any single quotes in your string with `\'`.

Comment: No worries, be sure to mark my answer as the solution, to help others in the future who have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Escape line 17 quotes `"` with `\"`